# Need a preg replace expression to replace muliple str_replaces to clean up some script

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am working with a script obfuscation class to output stored javascripts as a strings into a singlular output.

the problem is that customers of course will copy in the  or

I am currently using

```
    $script = str_replace('</script>', "", $script);
    $script = str_replace('<script>', "", $script);
    $script = str_replace('<script type="text/javascript">', "", $script);
```

But would love to use a preg_replace expression to handle it.

basically `<script + anything up to the >` and `</script>` would need to be removed.

I am not very familiar with regular expressions syntax as I have not worked with them in them much.

I do not want to use dom just in case that was going to be a suggestion.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You bother so much to replace the script tags why not use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php ?

Comment: You should learn how to use regular expressions instead of just asking someone to write it for you. www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Thanks for the link and the expression Barmar. I will teach myself regex as soon as I can pull my self away from projects long enough to get my head around them. Thanks :)

Comment: 1,000,001st comment to not use regex for this. Try PHP's strip_tags or something similar for this. Since you are trying to remove a script tag, you need to be careful to not leave any holes. also, I'd use htmlspecialchars to make everything into HTML so nothing gets "stripped" away yet they become neutralized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them into array:

```
 $replaces = array("</script>", "<script>", '<script type="text/javascript">');

 str_replace($replaces, "", $text)
```

or

```
preg_replace("/<\/?script.*?>/i", "", $text)
```